# read content of file and store it in jenksinsfile variable

Tags: shell, jenkins-pipeline

This should be super easy however i'm getting no resault when
i'm trying read content of file in my workspace and store it value in my jenkinsfile.

this is the code:

```
     steps {
        script {
        env.MYVAR = sh(script: "linux_version=`cat $WORKSPACE/VERSION.txt`",
                            returnStdout: true).trim()
        echo "This is the value of ${MYVAR}"          
    
        }
     }
```

from some reason i can't use MYVAR variable.

Comment: You are not returning anything from your command, you are just setting the value of the variable, instead try to return the value: `env.MYVAR = sh(script: "cat VERSION.txt", returnStdout: true).trim()`. Or just use the [readFile](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace) method: `env.MYVAR = readFile file: 'VERSION.txt'`

Comment: can I read file from /tmp or file should be in $WORKSPACE only ?